# Is it possible to catch and error on a response in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iot

Is it possible to catch an error on a response in MVC? Let's say if the calling unit no longer has a connection.

We have IOT devices that call our API where the call is processed for a few seconds before responding. We want to log if the requesting unit has not received the response. Is this possible in MVC?

```
private async Task<IActionResult> RespondAsync(CommunicationPackage response, Request request)
{
    var responseBytes = response.ToBytes();
    try 
    {
        return new FileContentResult(responseBytes, "application/octet-stream");
    }
    catch 
    {
        //Log error on unit no longer connected and response unable to be sent.
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a CancellationToken to your parameter list. This token is cancelled when the underlying tcp connection is detected as closed. But please be aware that a tcp connection has some delay until its considered dead. Furthermore if you send you response and the connections dies this approche will not help you.

Comment: @Darem Thank you for your comment. So you're saying it's impossible to tell if the requesting unit has received the response?

Comment: With my proposed approach it is not possible no. Basically HTTP/1.1 is not designed to provide this guarantee, because the client would have to confirm to the server that it has received the response and HTTP/1.1 does not support this out of the box. For this, there would have to be a corresponding logic in the application.

Comment: As @Darem says, this is not possible because HTTP is not designed for this. You're going to have to use something lower-level that will work in this manner, e.g. TCP.